# Does AWS S3 Charge for 403 requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In the [Amazon S3 pricing list](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) I saw that requests to the bucket costs money. 
If I configure my bucket to be private, hence other users would get 403 in case of request to my bucket, would requests like this cost me money?

I've found [AWS Forum: Charges for "403 Forbidden" and "404 Not Found"](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=58518) from more than a decade ago which explains the answer is yes, does anyone else knows if that's still the case?

It sounds very strange to me, especially considering there are many automatic tools that scan for buckets (and that's not even considering the case of intentional attack against specific bucket).

Thanks.

Comment: Is you bucket setup for static website hosting?  If so then someone would have to try to guess at file name.  If it's not then you only get a 404 when hitting the `http` version of it.  Scanning the bucket with the wrong credentials gives an access denied.  Are you worried about a DDOS type of attack that costs you money?

Comment: Exactly, you're saying someone has to guess it's name but it is possible with brute force tools and even used in many tools online (searching for public access buckets on the way). Once a bucket is found using one of these tools, one can use it in order to make the bucket owner pay for requests, even though the bucket owner made the bucket private (blocked for public access).

Comment: As for Requester Pays buckets (not normal buckets), the bucket owner is charged for 403 requests. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RequesterPaysBuckets.html
I'm not sure but it's natural to suppose that 403 requests to normal buckets are charged too.